# Is there a possibility to create a query based graph in google docs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Once more I request assistance.
Please elaborate if it is possible.
What I need to do is to make a graph out of one column, where the second column equals the one of interest. Please refer to the example in the attachment.
[Link to imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dSAL.jpg)

A close pseudo-code of what I want from google sheets:
*Select * from table1 where A='John'* and create a graph out of it later.

*If such was already asked, sorry, I was not able to find such.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, try this in cell `C1`:

`=query({A:B},"select Col2 where Col1 matches 'John' label Col2 'John stats' ",1)`

[image]

Then the pie chart range would be `C1:C10`.

Wrapping the range in `{}` changes the query notation to Col1,Col2 etc rather than A,B etc.